# selenium java NGWebdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have tried everything to login into one site using Selenium webdriver java, but there is one "window", which I don't know how to call it , that I couldn't find one way to click in order to access it.  Here, I open the firefox browser and lend on the parfumo.net webpage. The site loads "one window" with cookies settings...

```
public static void invokeBroser() throws InterruptedException {
            
                WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

                JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                
                NgWebDriver ngWebDriver = new NgWebDriver(js);
                ngWebDriver.waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
                
                driver.get("https://www.parfumo.net");
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                
                Thread.sleep(3000);
             // Initialize and wait till element(link) became clickable - timeout in 60 seconds
                WebDriverWait w = (WebDriverWait) new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(600));
                
                w.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Accept*')]")));


                      
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `Iframe` you have to first switch to it like below

```
driver.switchTo().frame("iframeId");
```

***OR***

```
driver.switchTo().frame("iframeName");
```

Once you switch to the frame than perform the click like below.

```
public static void invokeBroser() throws InterruptedException {
            
                WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

                JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                
                NgWebDriver ngWebDriver = new NgWebDriver(js);
                ngWebDriver.waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
                
                driver.get("https://www.parfumo.net");
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                
                Thread.sleep(3000);
             // Initialize and wait till element(link) became clickable - timeout in 60 seconds
                WebDriverWait w = (WebDriverWait) new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(600));

driver.switchTo().frame("sp_message_iframe_737779");

w.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Accept*')]")));
                      
    }
```

You can switch back to the main document like below:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```